# Spring boot push notification restTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, push-notification, resttemplate

I have a web application using spring boot as a back end and vue.js as a front end, and I have a script python capture frames and when get information send it to server and the last add a row to database, So I need to get notification, Can I use RestTemplate ? If yes how can I do it ?

```
@PostMapping("/plate")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createPositionOc(@RequestParam String plate) {

    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    List<Car> cars = carController.getAllCars();
    boolean exist = cars.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getPlate().equals(plate));

    List<Car> carsIn = carController.getAllCarsIn();
    boolean existIn = carsIn.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getPlate().equals(plate));


    List<Position> free = getAllPositiosFree();

    PositionOcp position = new PositionOcp(free.get(0).getId_pos(), plate, 
 myDateObj.format(myFormatObj));

    if (exist && free.size() > 0 && !existIn) {
        PositionOcp createdPositionOc = positionOcpRepository.save(position);
        //send notification
    }    

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to layer your code first.

Create a service and inject in your controller class. All the logic that you will write, should be in service layer. Not in your controller. Then you need the inject your repository layer in your service class. Thats the layering.

You created an endpoint in your Controller class..

```
@PostMapping("/plate")
public ResponseEntity<Plate> createPositionOc(@RequestParam String plate) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.createPosition(plate));
}
```

in your service layer you can easily add a row to database...

For your frontend ; you need the gave it something to use. You should return what you are gonna use in the front. Return them a model to use.

Resttemplate is for communicate the services. I cant ask a question , not quite understand phyton part.

Comment: i'm sorry for late response, so the script send the post request to endPoint "/plate" so I need to push notification to front

Comment: your script send post to your controller. Your controller handle your post and manipulate your data. When you say "public ResponseEntity<Plate>" ; frontend side can use your data.

Comment: but I need to get notification real time